# Не правильно работает onTouchEvent в Activity

Tags: android

Не правильно работает onTouchEvent в Activity.

Если использовать данный метод в Activity то нажатие будет работать только на ту область layout где добавлен через setContentView.

Если в основной FrameLayout добавить View. То в Activiy OnTouch не будет работать.

Мне надо чтобы можно было поймать событие при нажатии внутри Activity. На все Layout.

Делать для каждого View отдельный OnClick не получится. Логика приложения сломается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `onTouchEvent`, судя по Вашему описанию работает в точности так, как описывается - "Вызывается, если касание не обрабатывается ни одной `View`" (вольный перевод).

Если Вы хотите обрабатывать все события касания в `Activity`, то воспользуйтесь методом `dispatchTouchEvent` у `Activity`.

Не забывайте вызывать `super.dispatchTouchEvent`, чтобы события касания передавались далее `View`-элементам, находящимся в Вашем приложении.

Comment: Спасибо. щя протестим. Видимо это и есть оно

Answer (score 0):

Надо ловить не `onTouchEvent()`, а `onUserInteraction()`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {    
    @Override
    public void onUserInteraction() {
        super.onUserInteraction();
        //blah-blah
    }
}
```

В отличие от `onTouchEvent()` он срабатывает на весь `Activity`